# How to use express.static in none app.js folder?

Tags: node.js, express, static

I am trying to show the image by using express.static from a server side.

my folder is structure like this..

```
    public 
     /test.png
    routes
     /index.js
     /upload.js
    app.js
```

express.static works under app.js (http://localhost:4000/img/test.png)

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    app.use('/img', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    // Server Listen
    const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

    app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
    });
```

but it doent work under upload.js (http://localhost:4000/img/test.png)
what am i doing wrong here? the path seems to be the right one by consoling.

upload.js

```
    const express = require('express');
    const upload = express.Router();
    const cors = require('cors');
    const path = require("path");

    upload.use(cors());

    console.log(path.join(__dirname + '/../public'));
    upload.use('/img', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/../public')));

    module.exports = upload;
```

Here are my index.js and app.js

index.js

```
    const router = require('express').Router();
    const uploadRoutes = require('./upload');
    router.use('/upload', uploadRoutes);

    module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
     // Import thrid parties for APP
     const express = require('express');
     const cors = require('cors');
     const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
     const app = express();
     const routes = require('./routes');

     // App configuration
     app.use(bodyParser.json());
     app.use(cors());
     app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
       extended: false
      }));

     // Route Configuration
     app.use('/api', routes);


     // Server Listen
     const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

    app.listen(port, () => {
     console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
    });
```

thank you for looking over this.

Comment: Why can’t it just be in app.js?

Comment: ah ha! true! im so dumb :( it still works doesnt it !? thanks

Comment: No problem! I added an answer below, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be like `app.use('/img', express.static(__dirname + 'public'));`

Answer (score 0):

It isn’t necessary to use `express.static` in both files. It’s typically put in the entry file (app.js).

Here’s an example from the express [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) (notice that the `/` isn’t necessary):

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```